# Como usar a resposta do JSON?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json

Depois de muito tentar cheguei a esse resultado do JQUERY AJAX, mas ainda não consegui usar os dados do JSON, não funcionam, como devo fazer ? deem um Help ! obrigado

A resposta do JSON ta no fim

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#add-to-cart-head').submit(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this),
            dados = $this.serialize();
         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
   datatype: 'json',
            url: $this.attr('action'),
            data: dados,
   complete: function (mensagem) {
   $.getJSON($this.attr('action'), function(dados) {
      for(var i=0; i<dados.length; i++) {
        
                 $('#tbody-head-cart').append
     ('<tr class="cart-header-thumb">' +
           '<td class="cart-head-img">' +
     '<img src="' + dados[i].image + '" alt="" title="">' +
           '<div class="remove-add-cart-header">' +
                 '</div>' +
           '</td>' + 
      '<td class="cart-head-description">' +
             '<strong>' + dados[i].name + '</strong>' +
                      '<div>' + dados[i].tamanhos + '</div>' + '<div>' + cores + '</div>' +
        '</td>' +
       ' <td class="cart-head-price">' +
         ' <div class="strike"><strike>' + dados[i].price + '</strike></div>' +
           ' <span class="sale">' +  dados[i].saleprice + '</span>' +
             '<div class="cart-header-thmub-change">' +
             ' <input class="form-control" name="' + dados[i].cartkey + '" value="1" style="width: 50%;" type="text">' +
            '<a class="alter_qty" href="#" onclick="$(this).parents("form:first").submit(); return false;">' +
              'Alterar' +
              '</a></div><a class="alter_qty" href="#" onclick="$(this).parents("form:first").submit(); return false;">' +
            '</a>' +
                  '</td>' +
     ' </tr>');
       }
   });
          
   },
   error: function(){
                alert("message");
            }
    });
 return false;
});
});
```

```html
{"error":true,"message":"","total_items":1,"total":99,"cart_items":{"2099159d6749e3c101925ffc4bc24bbb":{"name":"Vestido","price":"99.00","saleprice":"89.00", "options":{"tamanhos":"p"}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repare que o seu JSON está inválido. Incompleto. Falta `}` no final. Para verificar se o JSON está correto pode usar o [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) que foi desenvolvido pelo criador da norma JSON.

Acrescentando `}` no final do seu JSON já valida certo e fica com este aspeto:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "",
    "total_items": 1,
    "total": 99,
    "cart_items": {
        "2099159d6749e3c101925ffc4bc24bbb": {
            "name": "Vestido",
            "price": "99.00",
            "saleprice": "89.00",
            "options": {
                "tamanhos": "p"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aí para converter num objeto JavaScript precisa usar o [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) e atribuir esse objeto a uma variável.

```
var objeto = JSON.parse(mensagem);
```

Neste objeto pode ir buscar os valores das propriedades que precisa, por exemplo assim:

```
objeto.error // dá true
objeto.total // dá 99
objeto.cart_items['2099159d6749e3c101925ffc4bc24bbb'].name // dá "vestido"
```

**Nota:** Propriedades de objetos que começam com numeros não podem ser acessadas da maneira `objeto.propriedade`, têm de ser com parenteses retos: `objeto['propriedade']`.

#### Exemplo online: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lwdfsc0/

Comment: Era isto que buscava, obrigado Sergio

Answer (score 1):

Muito simples amigo, a resposta do `AJAX` no `jQuery` quando requisitando um `JSON` é um objeto normal do Javascript. Vou usar este site aqui para os exemplos: http://www.jsontest.com

Inclusive você pode brincar um pouco lá também para pegar o jeito...

Veja essa página: http://ip.jsontest.com

Ela vai retornar o IP do usuário que está acessando ela como um JSON.

Se você fizer um request (aqui mesmo do SO) com jQuery no console, vai obter um objeto com um único parâmetro que é o IP.

```
{"ip": "000.000.00.000"}
```

Para ler basta fazer da mesma maneira que leria um objeto normal, usando a notação de ponto (`objeto.nome`) ou com colchetes (`objeto['nome']`);

```
var pessoa = {
    nome: 'Gladson',
    site: 'Stack Overflow'
};
pessoa.nome;
// ""Gladson"
pessoa.site;
// "Stack Overflow"
```

Execute este código no console:

```
$.get('http://ip.jsontest.com', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Ele vai retornar seu IP como um objeto, agora para pegar o valor do IP, execute este código:

```
$.get('http://ip.jsontest.com', function(data) {
    console.log(data.ip);
});
```

E pronto, ele vai retornar apenas o valor do IP e não o objeto completo.

Comment: Obrigado Waghcwb, vou ver os sites me indicou, pra entender essa linguagem.